# How do I make an emacs shortcut to switch between related files?

Tags: emacs, elisp

For example, I have the file model/user.py open and I want to have a shortcut that opens controller/user.py. Or I want to switch to test/model/testUser.py (contrived example)

I'd like to make an emacs shortcut which given a file currently open, opens files related in various ways.

Comment: "opens files related in various ways" you may want to get a lot more specific about the meaning of "various ways".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the "related files" follow some kind of pattern, I think it's trivial to write some elisp functions to do the task. Let's say you have a model and need to open his associated controller, you will need to do something like this:

```
(defun my-open-related-controller ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((name (buffer-file-name))) ;gets the filename of the current buffer
    ;; Of course, this is only an example. The point here is that you need
    ;; to "discover" the name of the related file based on the current one.
    (setf name (replace-regexp-in-string "model" "controller" name))

    ;; Now you will open the file(if it isn't open already) and switch to it
    (find-file name)))
```

Then you can bind the function to, say, F5:

```
(define-key name-of-the-mode-map [f5] 'my-open-related-controller)
```

If you want to crate this binding globally, use:

```
(global-set-key [f5] 'my-open-related-controller)
```

Of course, this is just a crude example(since you didn't give many specific details), but should be enough to get you started. Hope it helps!

Comment: So with elisp not having closures, is it possible to write this more generically? e.g. make a function that can be called as follows `(global-set-key [f5] (make-file-switcher "controller" "model"))`

Comment: Sure: `(defun make-file-switcher (from to) \`(lambda () (interactive) (find-file (replace-regexp-in-string ,(regexp-quote from) ,to (buffer-file-name) t t)))))`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't fancy writing this yourself and would rather customize an exisiting library, you may like to look at [toggle.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/toggle.el). It's designed to do what you're asking for.

Comment: I also liked it. Customization is the key. For exmaple, we can do dir1/filename dir2/filename while looking at similar files in 2 different directories.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [jump.el](https://github.com/eschulte/jump.el) that [rinari](https://github.com/eschulte/rinari) uses for this purpose (except for Ruby on Rails projects). I gave the second link, because rinari.el in this project contains settings that manage jumps from one place to another (controller to view, model, migrations, etc.).

It looks like you can get jump.el to jump to a particular method in a file - but that may take a bit of effort.